# Emacs Social Sciences Starter Kit - Not Loading

Tags: init-file, debugging

I am trying to install Kieran Healy's [Emacs Social Sciences Starter Kit](https://kieranhealy.org/resources/emacs-starter-kit/). I think I followed the instructions meticulously (details below) but – to cut to the chase – when I launch emacs, I get vanilla out-of-the-box emacs. In other words, it seems that emacs is not seeing the `init.el` and associated files.

All the files are (as expected) in`~/.emacs.d`, specifically in the subdirectory `~\.emacs.d\emacs-starter-kit-master/`.

Running `whoami` in Terminal returns `ljs46` so I have (as per the installation instructions) renamed `kjhealy.org` as `ljs46.org`. I have set the various paths for working in .tex (as per the instructions) but that shouldn't matter to the starter kit loading. But Emacs is not loading the .init file or any of the associated .org files.

Edited to add: if I specifically load the file by running `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/emacs-starter-kit-master/init.el")` then everything runs. So my question can I guess be reduced to, "How do I tell emacs to load this file by default on startup?"

The contents of the `emacs-starter-kit-master` subdirectory are as follows:

```
ljs46@lps023565 emacs-starter-kit-master % ls -a
.               starter-kit-completion.org
..              starter-kit-defuns.org
.gitignore          starter-kit-elpa.org
README.md           starter-kit-eshell.org
dominating-file.el      starter-kit-latex.org
elpa                starter-kit-lisp.org
eshell              starter-kit-misc.org
init.el             starter-kit-org.org
ljs46.org           starter-kit-python.org
snippets            starter-kit-stats.org
src             starter-kit-text.org
starter-kit-aspell.org      starter-kit.org
starter-kit-bindings.org    texmf
```

I am running Emacs 28.1 on MacOS 12.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The init file is in the wrong place. Emacs loads `~/.emacs.d/init.el`; it doesn’t know to load `~/.emacs.d/emacs-starter-kit-master/init.el`. Move everything into the `~/.emacs.d` directory.

Edit: if you don’t want to move the files to where they belong, your edit contains its own solution: just call `load` (or `load-file` if you prefer) in your init file.